# How to load a CSS spinner over my react component with opacity of 0.7?

Tags: css, reactjs

Okay, I have seen multiple ways out there which support css spinners but what I intend to create is a spinner over my actual page with opacity of about 0.7.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

class ReactClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const renderComponent = <div>Let's wrap spinner over this component</div>;
    return this.state.isLoading ? <Spinner /> : renderComponent;
  }
}

export default ReactClass;
```

here's how it looks:
[image]
How I want it to look like is overlay over the original `renderComponent` with a certain opacity.

Here's the live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-night-m86dr?file=/src/testcomponent.js), feel free to make changes. You can control Spinner movement by changing `this.state.isLoading` prop:

[image]

Kindly let me know if there's some way to do so. CSS Code of Spinner and the spinner component is also present in the live demo link and for your reference I am adding it here as well:

`Spinner.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./spinner.css";
const Spinner = (props) => {
  return <div className={"loader"}>Loading...</div>;
};

export default Spinner;

.loader {
  color: #330081;
  font-size: 8rem;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 72px auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation: load6 1.7s infinite ease, round 1.7s infinite ease;
  animation: load6 1.7s infinite ease, round 1.7s infinite ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load6 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em,
      0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  5%,
  95% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em,
      0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  10%,
  59% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, -0.087em -0.825em 0 -0.42em,
      -0.173em -0.812em 0 -0.44em, -0.256em -0.789em 0 -0.46em,
      -0.297em -0.775em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, -0.338em -0.758em 0 -0.42em,
      -0.555em -0.617em 0 -0.44em, -0.671em -0.488em 0 -0.46em,
      -0.749em -0.34em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  38% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, -0.377em -0.74em 0 -0.42em,
      -0.645em -0.522em 0 -0.44em, -0.775em -0.297em 0 -0.46em,
      -0.82em -0.09em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em,
      0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em;
  }
}
@keyframes load6 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em,
      0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  5%,
  95% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em,
      0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  10%,
  59% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, -0.087em -0.825em 0 -0.42em,
      -0.173em -0.812em 0 -0.44em, -0.256em -0.789em 0 -0.46em,
      -0.297em -0.775em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, -0.338em -0.758em 0 -0.42em,
      -0.555em -0.617em 0 -0.44em, -0.671em -0.488em 0 -0.46em,
      -0.749em -0.34em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  38% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, -0.377em -0.74em 0 -0.42em,
      -0.645em -0.522em 0 -0.44em, -0.775em -0.297em 0 -0.46em,
      -0.82em -0.09em 0 -0.477em;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em,
      0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes round {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes round {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing you need to take into account is that setting opacity on an element changes its stacking context. Also in the fiddle the spinner is coming before the underlying text so needs to be positioned absolutely. The order in which this is done seems to matter - I'll ponder some more on your specific use case.

Comment: Actually, though it's true that opacity changes the stacking I don't think that's the problem here - the problem seems to be that the spinner is pushing the underlying text down so it's not showing. I'll put up a simple fix in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei,change it to:

**testcomponent.js**

```
return (
  <>
    {renderComponent}
    {this.state.isLoading && <Spinner />}
  </>
);
```

**Spinner.js**

```
return (
 <div className={"loader-wrapper"}>
   <div className={"loader"}>Loading...</div>
 </div>
);
```

Also you should modify **spinner.css** file:
Add:

```
.loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

Remove:
from `.loader` remove margin

Comment: Just a quick doubt, what are those `<> and </>` used for?

Comment: React component require you to return only one element. `<></>` is like a wrapper which will disappear during build proccess. `<></>` is equal to `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` but shorter. In earlier versions of React you had to wrap different elements into ex. `div` which added not needed HTML. <br> take a look on article https://dev.to/tumee/react-fragments-what-why-how-2kh1 (fast google search to get it)

Answer (score 0):

You need the spinner not to take up space in the DOM else it pushes down the text following it  so make it position absolute. Also you can set the opacity here.

```
  .loader {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm can you just show your edits in the link I shared... cos what you said I tried doing it but it didn't work here it is again for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-night-m86dr?file=/src/Spinner.js

Comment: In the sandbox the underlying text is commented out so you can't see it. If the <!-- comment characters are removed and the two lines above added to the bottom of the .loader declaration it's fine. (I can't find how to change the HTML in the sandbox - I realise that's me being dim. I did it using browser dev tools in my test).

Comment: ahh... i see, hmm ok thank you so much for your time and inputs! For changing the html though, the root html sits in `public->index.html` folder